# pacman - Syy: error: failed retrieving file 'packages.db'

Tags: docker, manjaro, pacman, aws-cloud9

I run a Manjaro container inside an AWS Cloud9 machine with `docker container run --interactive --tty manjarolinux/build bash`, and the first command I run, `pacman -Syy`, fails with the following output:

```
# pacman -Syy
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'packages.db' from disk : Couldn't open file /build/packages/packages.db
error: failed to update packages (download library error)
 core                                                                                                          167.5 KiB   722 KiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################################] 100%
 extra                                                                                                        1986.5 KiB  2.37 MiB/s 00:01 [#####################################################################################] 100%
 community                                                                                                       5.8 MiB  3.10 MiB/s 00:02 [#####################################################################################] 100%
 multilib                                                                                                      192.6 KiB  0.00   B/s 00:00 [#####################################################################################] 100%
error: failed to synchronize all databases
```

`/build/` directory is empty, so that file doesn't exist.  What is the purpose of that file?  And how should I solve this problem?

I need to install packages in the container, but pacman seems useless right now.

---

`/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
#
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

#
# GENERAL OPTIONS
#
[options]
# The following paths are commented out with their default values listed.
# If you wish to use different paths, uncomment and update the paths.
#RootDir     = /
#DBPath      = /var/lib/pacman/
#CacheDir    = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
#LogFile     = /var/log/pacman.log
#GPGDir      = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
#HookDir     = /etc/pacman.d/hooks/
HoldPkg      = pacman glibc manjaro-system
# If upgrades are available for these packages they will be asked for first
SyncFirst    = manjaro-system archlinux-keyring manjaro-keyring
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -L -C - -f -o %o %u
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
#CleanMethod = KeepInstalled
Architecture = auto

# Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
#IgnorePkg   =
#IgnoreGroup =

#NoUpgrade   =
#NoExtract   =

# Misc options
#UseSyslog
#Color
#TotalDownload
CheckSpace
#VerbosePkgLists

# By default, pacman accepts packages signed by keys that its local keyring
# trusts (see pacman-key and its man page), as well as unsigned packages.
SigLevel    = Required DatabaseOptional
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional
#RemoteFileSigLevel = Required

# NOTE: You must run `pacman-key --init` before first using pacman; the local
# keyring can then be populated with the keys of all official Manjaro Linux
# packagers with `pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro`.

#
# REPOSITORIES
#   - can be defined here or included from another file
#   - pacman will search repositories in the order defined here
#   - local/custom mirrors can be added here or in separate files
#   - repositories listed first will take precedence when packages
#     have identical names, regardless of version number
#   - URLs will have $repo replaced by the name of the current repo
#   - URLs will have $arch replaced by the name of the architecture
#
# Repository entries are of the format:
#       [repo-name]
#       Server = ServerName
#       Include = IncludePath
#
# The header [repo-name] is crucial - it must be present and
# uncommented to enable the repo.
#

[packages]
SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
Server = file:///build/packages

[core]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# If you want to run 32 bit applications on your x86_64 system,
# enable the multilib repositories as required here.

[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# An example of a custom package repository.  See the pacman manpage for
# tips on creating your own repositories.
#[custom]
#SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
#Server = file:///home/custompkgs
```

Comment: share your /etc/pacman.conf

Comment: @Madhubala Done

Comment: Try `ping -c4 google.com`, and post the result.

Comment: Have you edited you /etc/pacman.conf file? Do you wanted to add custom repos?

Comment: @Madhubala I didn't. I just wanted to install git and a few tools and libraries. eyoung100, I will try that when I have a PC; AWS from the phone doesn't work very well

Comment: @eyoung100 That container doesn't even have `ping` installed: `# ping -c4 google.com` 
`bash: ping: command not found` xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment the 3 line about the custom repos.

```
[packages] 
SigLevel = Optional TrustAll  
Server = file:///build/packages
```

If you never modified it. I don’t know why the custom repos is set.
but you cerrtainly don’t use your own repos. So the custom repos have to be commented.

Comment: It worked.  However, given that the container doesn't have vi, it was very painful to comment those lines.  For anyone with the same problem in the future, I used these three lines: 1) `sed '/\[packages\]/s/^/#/' -i /etc/pacman.conf` 2) `sed '/\[packages\]/{n;s/^/#/;}' -i /etc/pacman.conf` 3) `sed '/\[packages\]/{n;n;s/^/#/;}' -i /etc/pacman.conf`